# how to re-enable the close(X) button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on vb6.net winforms. I have created two buttons named yes and no Respectively.I have disabled the close button use the following code shown below:

```
Private Const CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON As Integer = &H200
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim myCp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle Or CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON
        Return myCp
    End Get
End Property
```

My question is I want to re - enable it when the user completes his requirement by clicking on the yes button.

Comment: What is wrong with ControlBox=False in your WinForm property designer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to Override the CreateParams. You could easily turn off/on the Close button changing the property ControlBox of your form

```
Private Sub ClickMe(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.ControlBox = True

End Sub
```

Comment: with the control box property I cannot show the minimize and maximise boxes in form loading event. is there any way to show these boxes except the close buttton

Comment: Then look at this answer from HansPassant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075254/disable-close-button-in-windows-form?rq=1

Comment: I tried the code from the link provided stackoverflow.com/questions/3075254/… but it did not meet my requirements. Is there any way to re -enable the close button if we have disabled it.